libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: Emulator '/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64' does not support virt type 'kvm'
I am using ubuntu 20.04
krishna@krishna:~/veos-vm/images$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

I am trying to create a T0 toplogy:
https://github.com/sonic-net/sonic-mgmt/blob/master/docs/testbed/README.testbed.VsSetup.md#setup-vms-on-the-server using this link.
Facing issue while running the Setup VMs on the server.
below errors:
<172.17.0.1> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: libvirt: QEMU Driver error : unsupported configuration: Emulator '/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64' does not support virt type 'kvm'
<stdin>:18: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_virt_payload_8g451wqh/__main__.py", line 542, in core
    domain = v.define(xml)
  File "/tmp/ansible_virt_payload_8g451wqh/__main__.py", line 455, in define
    return self.conn.define_from_xml(xml)
  File "/tmp/ansible_virt_payload_8g451wqh/__main__.py", line 284, in define_from_xml
    return self.conn.defineXML(xml)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 4047, in defineXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainDefineXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: Emulator '/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64' does not support virt type 'kvm'```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_virt_payload_8g451wqh/__main__.py", line 593, in main
    rc, result = core(module)
  File "/tmp/ansible_virt_payload_8g451wqh/__main__.py", line 551, in core
    module.fail_json(msg='libvirtError: %s' % e.message)
AttributeError: 'libvirtError' object has no attribute 'message'```


Does your system have processor support for virtualization? If you look at /proc/cpuinfo, do you see any of the flags that indicate virtualization support?
